# Cannot requesting API of Spring-Boot while reading asynchronously E-Mail via IMAPS

Tags: spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc, connection

following situation. I have a Spring-Boot Application which handles two main features.

1. Reading asynchronously E-Mail from Server via IMAPS. (See below for configuration)
2. Providing an API for generating and reading **order** (this is my business object)

> The Problem is curious. If I start my Application without connection to IMAP and reading E-Mails I'm able to make any request to my API.
> But in the case of starting the E-mail Connection and reading E-Mails I'm not able to make any request to my API.

I receive always following error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8081
```

Can anyone help me and give me an advise how to handle this?

```
// Email Connection
        Store store = null;
        var props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", mailProperties.getProtocol());
        try {
            var session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            store = session.getStore();
            store.connect(
                    mailProperties.getHost(),
                    mailProperties.getUsername(),
                    decodeAsString(mailProperties.getPassword())
            );
            var inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            waitForNewMessages(inbox);
       ...

       inbox.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {
            @Override
            @SneakyThrows
            public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent ev) {
                for (Message message : ev.getMessages()) {
                    log.info("Message received subject={}, from={}", message.getSubject(), message.getFrom());
                    emailMessageHandler.handle(message);
                }
            }
        });
       ...


    private void waitForNewMessages(Folder inbox) throws MessagingException {
        while (inbox.isOpen()) {
            //every 25 minutes poke the server with a inbox.getMessageCount() to keep the connection active/open
            var scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
            final Runnable pokeInbox = () -> {
                try {
                    inbox.getMessageCount();
                } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                    //nothing doin'
                }
            };
            scheduler.schedule(pokeInbox, 25, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            ((IMAPFolder) inbox).idle();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching the whole www, I found the following solution `IdleManager`.
IdleManager uses an ExecutorService for listening for all events from the SMTP-Server and it doesn't block the Web-Application for other incoming request.

For getting in touch and more information you can see the following documentation.
[IdleManager](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IdleManager.html)

Answer (score 0):

Providing more details on the above question:

To monitor/ read incoming emails in a Spring Boot application via IMAP protocol:

1. We can use JavaMail API which provides implementation for IMAP.
2. We need an email server that supports IMAP IDLE feature, IMAP IDLE allows our application to receive immediate notifications when new messages arrive in the mailbox, rather than relying on periodic polling.

Refer detailed implementation of this here: https://medium.com/@sushant7/how-to-monitor-incoming-emails-in-a-spring-boot-application-indefinitely-7dabbdb74b2d